# Meteor simple hyperlink to template

Tags: meteor

Im using the meteor preview. I have a couple of hyperlinks on my page. Do I *have* to use javascript to make a hyperlink load a template? Is there an easier way to do this?

*Edit*: I ended up going backbone routing but if someone finds a git patch or if meteor gives a nicer way of doing this please answer

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK: Yes.

However, you don't **have** to trigger this via handlebar-render. I am for instance using a small piece of js to set a given Session variable, and then use conditions in the templates to choose specific templates based on the Session variable's content.